# Should I reuse SseEventSink or leave it open in JAX-RS?

Tags: jax-rs, server-sent-events

I have a JAX-RS SSE endpoint:

```
@Path("/")
@ApplicationScoped
public class RestRepo {

    @Context
    private Sse sse;

    // Would it be possible to share an EventSink from different clients (threads)
    // instead of re-creating on each request?
    @Context SseEventSink eventSink;

    @GET
    @Path("/sse")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void sendData(final @Context SseEventSink eventSink) {
      try (SseEventSink sink = eventSink) {
      ...   
      }
      // eventSink will be closed automatically 
      // because of "try-with-resources Statement", 
      // should I remove the "try-with-resources Statement" to leave it open?
    }

}
```

Everything works. However, would it make sense to keep `eventSink` open instead of closing it on every request, e.g. by

a) removing the `try (SseEventSink sink = eventSink)`-part or

b) using a shareable class instance (different threads)?

In fact, a new `EventSink`-instance is always created on every client call, and I doubt that's a good thing, as recreating such weight classes might not make much sense. What is the best practice here?

Comment: @BalusC: [sse] is the tag for x86 SIMD extensions, like `_mm_add_ps` / `addps` to add four floats with one instruction.  In a web context, you want [server-sent-events].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the cleanest way is to use the "try-with-resources" statement and close `SseEventSink` after each request.

`SseEventSink` must not be shared within a pool as it should be bound **always** to one request. `SseEventSink` is not a very heavy object like `WebSocket`.

And maybe in the future `SseEventSink` can be implemented internally by **Java Virtual Threads** (like all the other internal REST stuff, e.g. GET/POST-Request/Response) - it would be perfect for such "one thread per request" cases.

So the code above is considered the correct approach.

In summary: Do not share `SseEventSink` between different requests and close it once the response is send.